# Creating two lines for each item in legend with a superscript

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'd like to create a plot in R and I have two independent variables which I'd like to list each levels of the factors in the legend. The code I have now is a for loop. I'd like to have each item of the legend shown with the temperature and sediment shown on first time and the NTU shown on the second line.

**Example**:

```
29°C, 0 mg.cm^-2 (A)

(0 NTU)
```

**My code is below:**

```
for (tr in 1:8){ 

  for (s in 0:max(Sages)){
    h[s+1,tr]<-exp(-(u[tr]*s)^v[tr])
  }

  points(ds,h[,tr], xlim=c(0,85), ylim=c(0,1),type ='l', 
         lty=l[tr],col=cl[tr])

  Agetr<-Age[Treat==Streats[tr]]
  probtr<-prob[Treat==Streats[tr]]

  legend("topright", legend=c(
    expression("29°C, 0 mg.cm"^-2*"   \n (0 NTU)  (A)"),
    expression(paste("29°C, 30 mg.cm"^-2*"\n (3-8.83 NTU)")),
    expression(paste("29°C, 60 mg.cm"^-2*"\n (5.9-14.7 NTU)")),
    expression(paste("29°C, 120 mg.cm"^-2*" \n (13.2-29.2 NTU)")),
    expression(paste("31°C, 0 mg.cm"^-2*" \n (0 NTU)")),
    expression(paste("31°C, 30 mg.cm"^-2*" \n (3-8.83 NTU)")),
    expression(paste("31°C, 60 mg.cm"^-2*" \n (5.9-14.7 NTU)")),
    expression(paste("31°C, 120 mg.cm"^-2*" \n (13.2-29.2 NTU)"))
  ), lty=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
  col=c('black','blue','green3','red','black','blue','green3','red'),
  cex=0.75, text.width = 15)
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your formatting is a mess. Clean it up. Remove all the blank lines. They do not enhance readability

Comment: If you are going to use the `points` function, you will first need a plot device that is open for writing. Then the question will become: what are you trying to do with the two assignments that follow the `points` call? ( I would have expected the legend call to be outside the outer `for`-loop.)